# Rebus and RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, rebus

As mentioned in my previous question ([Rebus and Remote queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278539/rebus-and-remote-queues)) I am now working on remote queues vs. previous local queues and I'm using Rebus 0.83.  In this case my RavenDB is on a separate machine from my Rebus windows service.  I keep getting an error for "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080"  I am not using localhost anywhere in my code and I've checked my config and it's pointing to the correct url for RavenDB.  My configuration is

```
Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
    .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
    .Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
    .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
    .Subscriptions(s => s.Use(new RavenDbSubscriptionStorage(store, "Subscriptions")))
    .Sagas(s => s.Use(new RavenDbSagaPersister(store)))
    .CreateBus().Start();
```

I know i can reach RavenDB from the machine with Rebus because I've tried with a simple console app.  Any help is appreciated.

Entire error stack trace is here

```
15:17  [Warning] 10   User exception in Rebus 1 worker 1: Rebus.MessageHandleException: Could not handle message with ID 06729fcb-8a8f-4148-876a-8ed88c741cf7\2428 ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 340
at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 237
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectGet(String[] ids, String operationUrl, String[] includes, Boolean metadataOnly) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 1034
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass5e.<Get>b__5d(String u) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 991
at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:line 558
at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformer.cs:line 524
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 174
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Get(String[] ids, String[] includes, Boolean metadataOnly) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 991
at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.LoadInternal[T](String[] ids, String[] includes) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentSession.cs:line 313
at Raven.Client.Document.MultiLoaderWithInclude`1.Load(String id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\MultiLoaderWithInclude.cs:line 90
at Rebus.RavenDb.RavenDbSagaPersister.Find[T](String sagaDataPropertyPath, Object fieldFromMessage)   at Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.<Dispatch>d__c`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Turns out this was due to user permissions.  The default Local System can not send messages across machines and can't reach raven across machines either apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was due to user permissions. The default Local System can not send messages across machines and can't reach raven across machines either apparently